# Google Fit Data Aggregation by dataTypeName

Tags: rest, google-fit

I am trying to query the google fit api for aggregate data by dataTypeName as described here: https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate

The request body as follows will produce a combined aggregate of weight and body fat percentage

```
{
    'startTimeMillis': startTime,
    'endTimeMillis':endTime,
    'aggregateBy': [
        {'dataTypeName': 'com.google.weight'},
        {'dataTypeName': 'com.google.body.fat.percentage'}],
    'bucketByTime': {
        'durationMillis': durationWindow
    }
}
```

will result in only results for weight data merged from **different** sources.

If I do add a dataSourceId to the fat percentage object like:

```
{
    'startTimeMillis': startTime,
    'endTimeMillis':endTime,
    'aggregateBy': [
        {'dataTypeName': 'com.google.weight'},
        {'dataTypeName': 'com.google.body.fat.percentage',
       'dataSourceId':'raw:com.google.body.fat.percentage:******'}],
    'bucketByTime': {
        'durationMillis': durationWindow
    }
}
```

it will return values for both weight and body fat for the specified time range. Do I miss something inside the documentation?

Comment: Can you tell us what is your issue here?

Comment: The issue is that normally merging for the fat.percentage dataTypeName should work on its own(just like weight) but you have to provide a source which kind of defeats its use